# Show separate line not border

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to make a separate line as shown in this image.

[image]

This is what I am doing:

```
.separate-line {
    background-color: #D8D9DE;
    border-width: 0;
    color: #D8D9DE;
    height: 1px;
}
```

I added this html to show the border line:

```
<div>
<hr class="separate-line">
<input...>
</div>
```

The result shows a normal border. But I want to display a separate horizontal line.

Comment: You can see that there are two borders. border-top of the input container that is 1px and white, and another one is a border-bottom, which is 1px and the color might be #e0e0e0 (I'm not sure about the color.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your looking to create a two coloured/seperate lined `<hr>`, this is a way that you can do it

If you zoom in close, you can see the difference in colours between the top half of the line and the bottom half

I've added a darker background so you can notice the difference in colour

```css
.separate-line {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#fff;
    height: 2px;
    border:0;
    border-top:2px solid #aaa;
}

input {
  width: 96%;
  margin-left:2%;
}

body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <hr class="separate-line">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

For **Firefox** (some reason have to double hr height):

```css
.separate-line {
    background-color: #fff;
    color:#fff;
    height: 4px;
    border:0;
    border-top:2px solid #aaa;
}

input {
  width: 96%;
  margin-left:2%;
}

body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <hr class="separate-line">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: i test on chrome look different. more white space.

Comment: I'm using chrome 53 and it looks correct.. There is more white space simply because I increased the hr height to 2px instead of your 1px. You can change this back if you want it to be thinner

Answer (score 1):

Hello Try This This Might Help you as you want a separate border.

```
 hr {
display: block;
border-style: inset;
border-width: 2px;
background-color: #D8D9DE;
 }
```

you can increase the border using `border-width:`